# Javascript: Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339) on only one of all member functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple Javascript class in a Typescript file. I have reduced it to the skeleton below.

The error message is `Property 'cleanData' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)`

I can't see any difference between the declaration of cleanData() and the member functions on either side that seem to work fine...

What can I do to address this? Thanks.

```
export class Smokechart {
    constructor() {
    }
    addProps() {
    }
    cleanData() {
    }
    adjustScaleRange() {
    }
    fillSmoke() {
    }
    chart() {
    }
    computeMedianLine() {
    }
    computeSmokeAreas() {
    }
    _quantile() {
    }
    _calculateSmokeBounds() {
    }
}

const chainableInstance = new Smokechart()
chainableInstance
    .addProps()
    .cleanData() // <== Property 'cleanData' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)
    .adjustScaleRange()
    .computeMedianLine()
    .computeSmokeAreas()
    .fillSmoke()
    .chart()
    ._quantile()
    ._calculateSmokeBounds()
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from addProps, so of course the compiler won't let you chain another method.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jared Smith mentions in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381294/javascript-property-xxxx-does-not-exist-on-type-void-ts2339-on-only-one-o/63381479#comment112074451_63381294)

> You aren't returning anything from addProps, so of course the compiler won't let you chain another method.

It was too "skeletonized". Adding "return this" as the body for each of the methods made the error go away.